# How can I get configuration options of the gpg-agent? (on Git for Windows)

Tags: windows, gnupg

From the official manual (https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html).

There are a lot of options that I can **set**. But I can't just **get** them!

For example, how can I know `homedir` option value?

`gpg-agent --homedir` not working:

`gpg-agent[10888]: missing argument for option "--homedir"`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about `homerdir`, but [`gpgconf`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpgconf.html) lists all key options for `gpg-agent`.

Specifically, try running:

```sh
gpgconf -v --list-options gpg-agent
```